# Generators of Angular Momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, rotation

This semester I'm taking Quantum Mechanics II and we are in the theory of angular momentum. One particular thing got me thinking: when one does the representation of the rotations of the $SO(3)$, a direct result is that the components of the total angular momentum are the generators of rotation. Is this a purely mathematical statement from group theory or it has any other physical meaning? What would it mean for a physical quantity to be the generator of rotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does have physical significance. Due to [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), generators of a symmetry are conserved quantities. Hence, stating that angular momentum generates rotations means that, in rotationally-invariant systems, angular momentum is conserved.